# Devise users/sign_in and users/show action trouble

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I user devise 3.4.0 under rails 4.1.0.

I want to add user detail page, so I made this route

```
get 'users/:id' => 'users#show', as: 'user'
```

But after this, when I access /users/sign_in path, it try to find the user show page.

How to write the right route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did will actually "override" the devise routes (and i think this is the problem you are facing)

If you want to add another route in the scope of devise routes, you have to do something like :

```
devise_scope :user do
  get '/users/:id' => 'users#show'
end
```

after

```
devise_for :users
```

Let me know if it solves the problem !